# PDF Show blank on node.js running on serverless

Tags: node.js, serverless

I want to get pdf from the url using node.js (express) on serverless application using request module. and then render it to the browser.

PDF File: http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf

But I got blank PDF shows up (but it show the correct pdf title "Create a PDF File", see on screenshot below). 
[image: pdf blank]

I use serverless, and use express to routing and showing API. here is my functions declaration on serverless.yml

```
functions:
  api-v1:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Here is my code

```js
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')

exports.getPdf = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    request.get({ url: 'http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf', encoding: 'binary'}, (error, response, body) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('asd.pdf', body, 'binary'); // save to asd.pdf file
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

      res.send(body) // render to web
    })
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
}
```

If I just run it with normal express server using app.listen, it works perfectly. But when I used serverless, this shows blank. So I believe there  was serverless (or my config) things that make this show blank page. Is there something missing in my serverless config?